# Unexpected ArrayStoreException

Tags: java

Why does the following code throw `ArrayStoreException`?

```
double[] a = {2.0,3.4,3.6,2.7,5.6};
int[] b = {2,3,4,5};
System.arraycopy(b,0,a,1,4);
```

Comment: If you claim that your code throws an exception, then you should at least post code that compiles.

Comment: +1.  someone edit that to at least say double[] a and int[] b

Comment: Now that the question is properly formatted and worded, please remove your downvotes.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From the docs for [`System.arraycopy`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html):

> Otherwise, if any of the following is
>   true, an ArrayStoreException is thrown
>   and the destination is not modified:
>
> [...]
>
> The src argument and dest argument
>   refer to arrays whose component types
>   are different primitive types.

That's exactly the case here - `int` and `double` are different primitive types, so the exception is thrown as documented.

The point of `arraycopy` is that it can work blindingly fast by copying the raw data blindly, without having to apply any conversions. In your case it *would* have to apply conversions, so it fails.

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, that's the documented behavior for an `arraycopy` between arrays with different primitive types as components.  Whether the type could normally be promoted isn't relevant; this is what `arraycopy` is designed to do.

Answer (score 0):

try double**[]** a = {2.0,3.4,3.6,2.7,5.6};
and
int**[]** b

Answer (score 0):

There is no automatic conversion between int and double elements in the array with arraycopy(). The native method checks for array type equivalence and throws the ArrayStoreException on mismatch. You'll have to revert to the plain or method of looping:

```
for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++)
    a[i] = b[i];
```